# flutter I want remove top my project name

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I upgraded flutter latest version

but suddenly showing is my project name(my_projct_first2) on the top

How can I remove this?

thanks in advance

Comment: You mean on App Bar?

Comment: I cant upload image ,
above the app bar.

Comment: You can edit the question and put the image there

Comment: I linked an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I know from the image is, thats an AppBar, you can remove it by delete this part on `Scaffold`

```
 appBar: AppBar(
    title: Center(child: Text("Your Title)),
 ),
```

Comment: this is not Appbar ㅜㅜ

Comment: Did you use `SliverAppBar`? Maybe you can share your code.

Comment: I dont use SliverAppBar

Comment: Okay, I think its better if you put your code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have used an appbar for the same. You can try with below code snippet.

```
appBar: AppBar(
title:Text(""),
),
```